# How can i access a file in local?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get an image that is uploaded from the user.

Upload function:

```
public function updatedUpload($upload){
    $object = $this->currentTeam->objects()->make(['parent_id' => $this->object->id]);
    $object->objectable()->associate(
        $this->currentTeam->files()->create([
            'name' => $upload->getClientOriginalName(),
            'size' => $upload->getSize(),
            'path' => $upload->storePublicly('files', ['disk' => 'local'])
        ])
    );

    $object->save();
    $this->object = $this->object->fresh();
}
```

This gets me this link in the database:

```
files/9yzPCLZzlT2aiogc8A8DQIdJTNrkiZ0eu0QTESFF.jpg
```

How can i access this through an image so i can see the picture?

Answer (score 0):

While saving the file, you used the steatement:

`$upload->storePublicly('files', ['disk' => 'local'])`

This `storePublicly()` method return the path instead of the file itself. As a result the path where the file is stored is being shown. Which is not incorrect. Just check the returned file path and check if that file exists or not.

Now, what exactly you expect from the database? The file content? Or you want to show the file in html?

If you want to see the file content then you can use:

`get_file_contents($this->object->path);`

Or if you want to see the file in web page using blade, then:

`<img src="{{$this->object->path}}">`

Answer (score 0):

The image will save on your disk in this address

```php
    http://your-site.com/storage/files/9yzPCLZzlT2aiogc8A8DQIdJTNrkiZ0eu0QTESFF.jpg
```

And you can access it in your blade file via this

```php
    asset_url("files/9yzPCLZzlT2aiogc8A8DQIdJTNrkiZ0eu0QTESFF.jpg")
```